# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in three.js

Tags: three.js

So I'm beginning to learn three.js and I'm following a tutorial step by step, but i get the error above.

here's the code with issues:
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()

const vertex1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)
geometry.vertices.push(vertex1)

const vertex2 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
geometry.vertices.push('vertex2')

const vertex3 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)
geometry.vertices.push('vertex3')

Can somebody please explain why push isn't working? Even if I define an empty array.

Also, the tutorial uses const geometry = new THREE.Geometry(), but I get an error saying Geometry is not a constructor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Geometry` is deprecated and no part of the library core anymore. You have to use `BufferGeometry`. However, `BufferGeometry` has no `vertices` property since vertex data are managed in form of buffer attributes. The above code should look like so:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

const vertices = [];
vertices.push( 0, 0, 0 );
vertices.push( 0, 1, 0 );
vertices.push( 1, 0, 0 );

geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );
```

More information about the `Geometry` removal in the following `three.js` forum topic:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401